# Geotools: ClassNotFoundException: javax.measure.spi.SystemOfUnits

Tags: geotools

I am trying to implement a really basic code to get started with Geotools, but it doesn't work out:

```
package com.henrytriage.windows;

import org.geotools.data.DataStore;
import org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.FeatureSource;
import org.geotools.feature.FeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.feature.FeatureIterator;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;
import org.opengis.filter.Filter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File file = new File("filepath");
        System.out.println(file.exists() + " " + file.length());
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("url", file.toURI().toURL());

        DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(map);
        String typeName = dataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
        FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> source = dataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);
        Filter filter = Filter.INCLUDE;

        FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> collection = source.getFeatures(filter);

        try (FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> features = collection.features()){

            while (features.hasNext()) {
                SimpleFeature feature = features.next();
                System.out.println(feature.getID() + ": \n" + feature.getDefaultGeometryProperty().getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After trying lots of different libraries and packages I am still getting the
`ClassNotFoundException: javax.measure.spi.SystemOfUnits`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched from Gradle to a Maven Project. This fixed the issue. There may be a solution for Gradle when handling dependencies, which get imported more than once, in a correct manner, but I didn't figure it out...
@ian-turtor thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The jar file containing that class should be pulled in when you add `gt-main` to your project.

```
[INFO] +- org.geotools:gt-main:jar:29.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.geotools:gt-referencing:jar:29.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ejml:ejml-ddense:jar:0.41:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ejml:ejml-core:jar:0.41:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-metadata:jar:29.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.geotools:gt-opengis:jar:29.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- systems.uom:systems-common:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- javax.measure:unit-api:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- si.uom:si-quantity:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- si.uom:si-units:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |     \- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- tech.units:indriya:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- tech.uom.lib:uom-lib-common:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.geotools.ogc:net.opengis.ows:jar:29.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.geotools.ogc:org.w3.xlink:jar:29.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- it.geosolutions.jgridshift:jgridshift-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.sf.geographiclib:GeographicLib-Java:jar:1.49:compile
```

Comment: `si.uom:si-quantity:2.1
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- javax.measure:unit-api:2.1.2 -> 2.1.3
|    |    |    |    |    \--- si.uom:si-units:2.1
|    |    |    |    |         +--- javax.measure:unit-api:2.1.2 -> 2.1.3
|    |    |    |    |         +--- si.uom:si-quantity:2.1 (*)`
I am implementing
`implementation 'org.geotools:gt-main:29.0'`
But still the same error...
@ian-turton

Comment: what does `mvn dependency:tree` show for your pom?

Comment: [link](https://codefile.io/f/CZ8xbDXCHj) I am using gradle, here can you find my dependency trees @ian-turton

Comment: you have picked up a newer version of javax.measure:unit-api:jar you have 2.1.3 rather than 2.1.2 - something may have changed?

Comment: Ok, now it worked out, but it still says Module javax.inject not found, required by tech.units.indriya, although inject is there

Comment: AFAIK none of the GeoTools team use Gradle so this is probably never tested, Everything seems to be working fine with maven and Java 11, are you possibly using Java 17 which is untested?